# Why are these two JavaScript function call having same "this" value?

Tags: javascript

Title says it all. So far i understood, `this` keyword refers to context  where the current function is invoked. But why are these two function invocation referring same `num` variable?

```
var num = 0;

function demo() {
    this.num++;
}

function caller() {
    var num = 0;
    demo();
    console.log("caller " + num);// 0
}

demo();
console.log("global " + num);// 1

caller();
console.log("global " + num);// 2
```

Comment: this ... looks like a homework question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your global functions, this is referring to the `window` object. Inside of the `caller` function, `num` is outputting the local variable.  Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/det0efc3/) to look at. Also, this [article](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascripts-this-with-clarity-and-master-it#The_use_of_this_in_the_global_scope) helps to explain more about using `this`. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

By default, `this` is the global object (`window`).

When you declare a variable in top-level code (as opposed to in a function), it becomes a property of the global object.

Therefore, `this.num` and the global `num` variable are the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

this is dependent based on call-site (the place from where the method is called containing this). As you are calling demo() first so this is representing window (i.e. global). As num is already declared on global space so caller method will use the global one and will ignore redefining it.

Answer (score 0):

since your inital var num has value assigned 0, demo() has this referring to global `window`object, calling `demo()` increments the global `num`

calling `demo()` and `caller()` both increment global `num`

Answer (score 0):

The `this` holds the context object. As the function are not a part of any object, they belong to the general `window` object, just like the `num` - they're all running in the same context. (`this`=`window`)

Answer (score 0):

`this` in `demo` will refer to the `window` object, since the function seems to be a member of the global variable (window), therefor whenever you're calling `demo`( or `caller`, since this function just calls `demo`), the global `num` variable will be incremented.

The `num` variable in `caller` however is a local variable and overrides the global variable within the caller function, but since you're never performing any calculations on this variable; it will always remain 0.